# ggplot2: Adding arrow messes up legend entries

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to make a scatterplot of two groups and then add an arrow. But I don't want the arrow to show up in the legend entries or mess up the previous legend entries.

Here's my example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~country, ~series1, ~series2, 
  #--|--|----
  "USA", 8, 5,
  "USA", 9, 6, 
  "USA", 11, 7, 
  "USA", 10, 8,
  "USA", 11, 4,
  "USA", 14, 10,
  "USA", 16, 12,
  "USA", 12, 8,
  "USA", 12, 13,
  "USA", 13, 10,
  "USA", 11, 5,
  "FRA", 5, 6, 
  "FRA", 6, 8, 
  "FRA", 5, 7, 
  "FRA", 4, 8,
  "FRA", 9, 11,
  "FRA", 7, 9, 
  "FRA", 14, 11,
  "FRA", 7, 11, 
  "FRA", 6, 6,
  "FRA", 5, 7,
  "FRA", 4, 5
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = series1, y = series2, color = country)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 4, xend=6, y = 11, yend=8), 
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")))
```

Which gets me:

[image]

That somehow does something to how the legend is displayed (it puts a strange arrow in there).

*(I have two small follow-up questions: 1) How do you change the width of the arrow and 2) how do you change the alpha of the arrow?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `show.legend = FALSE` to the `geom_segment` geom. `grid::arrow` doesn't mention anything about the length of the "wings". You will have to dig into the code.